# How to use Libertine?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, nmap

I'm trying to run nmap on my Ubuntu Touch phone. I was advised to use Libertine to install `deb` packages. It is installed now but when I go to terminal to check if I can use it `nmap --help` it gives me `nmap command not found`.

How does Libertine work ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer:

`libertine-container-manager exec -i CONTAINER-IDENTIFIER -c "nmap --help"`

Answer found in the docs [here](http://docs.ubports.com/en/latest/userguide/dailyuse/libertine.html)

Answer (score 0):

Besides using the UI option on the system preferences. You can see how to use Libertine on the [official UBports documentation about desktop apps](https://docs.ubports.com/en/latest/userguide/dailyuse/libertine.html?highlight=libertine#).